# How to hide popup automatically within 3 seconds.

Tags: javascript, jquery

i need to display popup for 3seconds while clicking button.then the popup will auto hide after 3seconds.
It works only first time clicking button after that the popup cannot hide.
please help me how to do this.

thank you.

```
    <div id="notification" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" style="font-family: "Roboto Condensed",sans-serif!important;"><?php if($theme_options->get( 'confirmation_text', $config->get( 'config_language_id' ) ) != '') { echo $theme_options->get( 'confirmation_text', $config->get( 'config_language_id' ) ); } else { echo 'Confirmation'; } ?></h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p></p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="button modal-left-button"  data-dismiss="modal"><?php if($theme_options->get( 'continue_shopping_text', $config->get( 'config_language_id' ) ) != '') { echo $theme_options->get( 'continue_shopping_text', $config->get( 'config_language_id' ) ); } else { echo 'Continue shopping'; } ?></button>
                <a href="<?php echo $shopping_cart; ?>" class="button modal-right-button"><?php if($theme_options->get( 'checkout_text', $config->get( 'config_language_id' ) ) != '') { echo $theme_options->get( 'checkout_text', $config->get( 'config_language_id' ) ); } else { echo 'View Cart'; } ?></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

this my jquery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('body').on('click', '.quickview a', function () {
    $('#quickview .modal-header .modal-title').html($(this).attr('title'));
    $('#quickview .modal-body').load($(this).attr('rel') + ' #quickview_product' ,function(result){
        $('#quickview').modal('show');
        $('#quickview .popup-gallery').magnificPopup({
            delegate: 'a',
            type: 'image',
            tLoading: 'Loading image #%curr%...',
            mainClass: 'mfp-img-mobile',
            gallery: {
                enabled: true,
                navigateByImgClick: true,
                preload: [0,1] // Will preload 0 - before current, and 1 after the current image
            },
            image: {
                tError: '<a href="%url%">The image #%curr%</a> could not be loaded.',
                titleSrc: function(item) {
                    return item.el.attr('title');
                }
            }
        });
    });
    return false;
});  
    setTimeout(function() { $('#notification').modal('hide'); }, 3000);
```

Comment: Put the timeout behing the $('quickview').modal("show"); ...

Comment: But it does not work jonas..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('body').on('click', '.quickview a', function () {
    $('#quickview .modal-header .modal-title').html($(this).attr('title'));
    $('#quickview .modal-body').load($(this).attr('rel') + ' #quickview_product' ,function(result){
        $('#quickview').modal('show');
        $('#quickview .popup-gallery').magnificPopup({
            delegate: 'a',
            type: 'image',
            tLoading: 'Loading image #%curr%...',
            mainClass: 'mfp-img-mobile',
            gallery: {
                enabled: true,
                navigateByImgClick: true,
                preload: [0,1] // Will preload 0 - before current, and 1 after the current image
            },
            image: {
                tError: '<a href="%url%">The image #%curr%</a> could not be loaded.',
                titleSrc: function(item) {
                    return item.el.attr('title');
                }
            }
        });
    });
    return false;
    setTimeout(function() { $("#notification").hide(); }, 3000);
});
```

Comment: thank you luissimo it works,but the popup background cannot hide.

Comment: i no need to refresh page ,but it works only after refreshing page.

Comment: thank u lussimo it works only first time clicking button ,after that the popup cannot hide.

Comment: i tried your edited code lussimo but it works only onetime,next time clicking  Add to cart button

Comment: sorry,it doesnot works lussimo..anyway thank you very much for spending time to solve this.

Comment: Yeah i don't know why it only works once, if a button with a click event handler works once it should work all the time. Sorry i'm out of further ideas.